# Target.Closest equivalent for IE11

Tags: javascript

Bear with me, I'm clueless on javascript.

```
function onTableClick(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('td').innerHTML == "Edit") {
        let myElement = document.querySelector("#JamHeadTable");
        myElement.style.opacity = 1;
        var id = e.target.closest('tr').id.split("_")[1];
        editTableRow(id);
    }
}
```

I've got this function that has worked fine in Chrome and Edge but I just tried debugging my ASP.Net site in Visual Studio on Internet Explorer 11 and it breaks on the first line:

```
 if (e.target.closest('td').innerHTML == "Edit")
```

Is there an equivalent I can use other than `e.target.closest('td')` to make it IE11 compatible? Baring in mind I also use `e.target.closest('tr')` a couple of lines down.

Comment: [Always look at MDN first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find polyfills

Comment: I don't know what a polyfill is

Comment: Now you know :) You did not need to know the word to look at the function at MDN

Comment: It's way's of making old browsers run new JS functions,..  There is also something called trans-piling that add new syntax support,  you might need to look into that too if you want to use modern JS features on out-dated browsers.

Comment: I copy-pasted the closest polyfiller into my page scripts and it's working as intended so now I get the purpose, but I'll have a google of trans-piling too.